# cannot remove vlan names

Tags: cisco, vlan

Hi I was practicing creating vlans and assigning them to ports however I cannot remove the names.

```
CCNA-SWITCH1#show vlan

VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- -------------------------------
1    default                          active    Fa0/1, Fa0/2, Fa0/3, Fa0/4
                                                Fa0/5, Fa0/6, Fa0/7, Fa0/8
                                                Fa0/9, Fa0/10, Fa0/11, Fa0/12
                                                Fa0/13, Fa0/14, Fa0/15, Fa0/16
                                                Fa0/17, Fa0/18, Fa0/19, Fa0/20
                                                Fa0/21, Fa0/22, Fa0/23, Fa0/24
                                                Gi0/1, Gi0/2
1002 fddi-default                     act/unsup
1003 trcrf-default                    act/unsup
1004 fddinet-default                  act/unsup
1005 trbrf-default                    act/unsup
```

---

```
CCNA-SWITCH1#show ip interface brief
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES manual administratively down down
Vlan2                  unassigned      YES manual up                    down
Vlan3                  unassigned      YES manual up                    down
FastEthernet0/1        unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet0/2        unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet0/3        unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet0/4        unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet0/5        unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
FastEthernet0/6        unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
 --More--
```

I tried to remove vlan 2 and 3 
i used the command no vlan 2 etc.. but they still showing

Comment: Have you tried deleting the vlan database with the command delete flash:vlan.dat?

Comment: @user4946, removing the vlan.dat will not remove the SVI configuration.  In the OP output, the VLANs are already removed, it is the SVIs that remain.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

It appears you created both the VLANs and the SVI (virtual interfaces).

While the `no vlan 2` would (and did according to your `show vlan` output) remove the VLAN, it won't remove the SVI (which show up when you show the interfaces with `show ip interface brief`).

To remove the SVI, you need to issue the `no interface vlan 2` command as well.

Comment: Thanks that's great I give it a try and let you know the outcome

Answer (score 5):

Try `no interface vlan 2` and `no interface vlan 3` in global config mode.